# How to use JDBC on working Hibernate/Spring web-app?

Tags: hibernate, spring, jdbc

I have working Hibernate/Spring web-app (`HibernateDaoSupport`, `getHibernateTemplate()`, etc). For several tasks i need to use JDBC (jdbcTemplate ?). How to do it in that scenerio ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just create `JdbcTemplate` and use the same `DataSource` that is being used by `HibernateDaoSupport`, `HibernateTemplate`. Hibernate is just a fancy library working on top of JDBC `DataSource`/connection. You might use it manually. Try:

```
@Autowired
private DataSource ds;
```

If you are lucky, this should work. A better idea is to create `JdbcTemplate` as a Spring bean and inject proper data source:

```
<bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.coreJdbcTemplate">
  <constructor-arg ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>
```

Consider using `JdbcOperations` interface, also look at [SimpleJdbcOperations](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/simple/SimpleJdbcOperations.html).

```
@Autowired
private JdbcOperations jdbc;
```

If you start to access the same database/connection pool both by Hibernate and using direct JDBC access code, you have to watch out for some side effects:

- Hibernate L2 cache is not aware of JDBC modifications
- JDBC code is not aware of Hibernate optimistic locking
- transaction management
- ...

---

Another approach is to access JDBC connection used by Hibernate session (in `HibernateDaoSupport`:

```
getSession().connection()
```

Comment: Great, but class="org.springframework.jdbc.coreJdbcTemplate" should be class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate"

Answer (score 3):

You may use [`Session.doWork`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/api/org/hibernate/Session.html#doWork%28org.hibernate.jdbc.Work%29) to execute code using JDBC connection used by Hibernate.

This of course requires that you use and have access to Hibernate's Session object.